# "use of unassigned variable" compile error that will never happen

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have the following code, which results in a compile error, despite seemingly being correct:

```
bool aBool = SomePredicate();
if (!aBool && !OutFunction(out int value))
{
    return;
}
int result = -1; //other code here...
if (!aBool && SomeCondition(result, value)) // CS0165: Use of unassigned variable 'value'.
{

}
```

The variable `aBool` is not modified between the two conditions, meaning that if `aBool` was false during the first check it'll always be assigned.
Otherwise, if `aBool` was true, then the variable would never be used, as the expression should end once the first part is evaluated.

Despite this, why does this result in a compile error? (C# 7.3)
Additionally, what is the best way to get around it?

Main focus is on the "Why?" part

Comment: If `aBool` is true then the first `if` will be [short-circuited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) and `OutFunction()` will NOT be called - hence `value` will be uninitialised.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Sure, but logically it's impossible that `value` is uninitialised because of  `!aBool`. I guess that the compiler is simply not clever enough to see it.

Comment: you should declare `value` before the if statement and give it a default value, or (I'm not sure if this will work) use `&` instead of `&&`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I guess the analysis isn't good enough to work that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` is a [short-circuiting `AND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) so if `!aBool` is evaluated to `false`, `!OutFunction(out int value)` is never evaluated and the method continues, so at  `SomeCondition(result, value)` `value` can be not initiated.

You can try using [Logical AND operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-and-operator-):

```cs
bool aBool = SomePredicate();
if (!aBool & !OutFunction(out int value))
{
    return;
}
int result = -1; //other code here...
if (!aBool && SomeCondition(result, value))
{

}

bool SomePredicate() => false;
bool OutFunction(out int i) => false;
bool SomeCondition(int i, int j) => false;
```

So it always executes ([Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTARgPasA26AhgELtcAvOgDKrALYBTAAoAnScACWAY24AXSXQDcjJkUUAzdNQCEfAegBk6EwHkArmqgBWNYtYA7aq0fpFHtXQAN24Oe0laWl09AiQ9eMwAdh04hIBfaKZ/QPkAZ3sOQOEAWjgtdAB6CtY1AAtJWXRlVmBJdHr5ADpuzOJDYzN+TitrMSlsTyU3T2o8grUAGmDQ8MjKipwRAAY4ADZnEHQAVVy21iN7D25c3MUAcw8FZdlFbmYONoByELDJT87ekRYoD0BkkCC2MMxjJ5EpVBo6OhBAA+dAGUKnFIJdCQrgOJyudxeHyBbJ+ego9B1WSsADu6Ee9IAogAPZSSAAO0y8tBSEIs0ImHimROoZMUSzJACsKaj0RxMdEwWkgA)). Or rewrite code in some other way (for example by declaring and initializing the variable before the `OutFunction` call).

Compiler has some limitations of conditional flow and definite assignment analysis when it comes to such checks and it seems that this is one of the corner cases. Some of them were recently fixed for later compilers with C# 10 feature [Improved Definite Assignment Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/improved-definite-assignment).

**UPD**

From the discussion [@github.com/dotnet/csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7291) several useful links were referenced, [one of them](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36927#issuecomment-508595947) stating the following:

> To provide a little background, the compiler does what is usually referred to as a "path-independent flow analysis" for these situations. What this means practically is that conditional states are intersected at the end of the condition.

and

> One way to learn about the states would be to do what's called a "path-dependent" flow analysis, but that can be significantly more expensive and is not in the design of C# 8.

So the simpler [mre] would be just:

```cs
using System;

bool aBool = SomePredicate();
int value;

if (!aBool)
{
    value = 1;
}

if (!aBool) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(SomeCondition(value));// CS0165: Use of unassigned variable 'value'.
}

bool SomePredicate() => false;
bool SomeCondition(int i) => false;
```

[@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDIEYHt0BsAEBDAIU1wF4cBldAWwFMAFAJxuAEsBjPAFxoAoBKANzIWAO044AbniwBXGkJRIWAMxw8AhIWJ9kAb2Q5Dk6XJxk4CgL7JhqjVux8ceg4ahwAnD0q0AwuhFWThYAnilZGj5BAHponF9yAAY4ADYAVhAcAFUAZxocdFUZETwcnJYAcxFmYwYWPFQsfIBycLlmgDpka0UMbApqeiZWDm5+MwA+HGVpPIU+3B8af0CWYNDRcRYnEimZrDmgA==)

Comment: The main focus of the question is the "Why" part. For reasons mentioned in the original post, it shouldn't matter if it wasn't initialized precisely because it's a short-circuiting AND. This is a good, short workaround though, so I'll upvote regardless, and wait for a bit more before marking as correct (in case someone answers the "Why" part)

Comment: " so at SomeCondition(result, value) value can be not initiated" in thoery but never in this case because `aBool` must be `false` in that case the value is initialised. Using `&` is not a solution if `OutFunction` can only be used if `SomePredicate` is false.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Good to know that this has been addressed in future versions.

Comment: @BálintPécsi this one has not. I think that in this case it becomes quite cumbersome  to diagnose such edge cases. I vaguely remember some a bit similar cases being missed by compiler. Will create a github issue to confirm.

Comment: There's a tension between compiling speed and accurate flow analysis. I would imagine that making the flow analysis more thorough could slow down the compile speed unacceptably.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do something similar to this, you can define the variable with a value that does not affect your logic (in this example 0 ):

```
        bool aBool = SomePredicate();

        int value = 0;  // Initialize with some other value

        if (!aBool && !OutFunction(out value))
        {
            return;
        }
        int result = -1; //other code here...
        if (!aBool && SomeCondition(result, value)) 
        {

        }
```